# Getting "Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed."

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Hi i am getting **"Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.**" warning while getting data from local DB and i am not getting any data from DB because of this error.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a **specific problem** with the **complete error message and/or stacktrace** and the **shortest code necessary** to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).